# Issue while using Sqoop to connect to database

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I have an issue while running simple sqoop to list tables in Oracle directory. I am using CDH 5.5.1

There is a jar file ojdbc6.jar inside below directory:

```
/var/lib/sqoop
```

When I run a simple sqoop to list tables:

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@host_name:port/database_name --username user_name --password passwd

or,

sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:oracle:thin@host_name:port:database_name --username user_name --password passwd
```

Error I get:

```
Warning: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/bin/../lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/28 14:04:39 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.1
16/10/28 14:04:39 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/28 14:04:39 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
16/10/28 14:04:39 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/10/28 14:04:39 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.listTables(OracleManager.java:759)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListTablesTool.run(ListTablesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking some docs I see that the options you are specifying are sqoop options.
Sqoop2 runs by a script as a first argument, or runs in interactive mode based on the source of SqoopShell class (checked it on GrepCode).
Now as you have a first argument, it tries to find and open list-tables as a scriptfile that contains sqoop2 commands which obviously fails as you do not have such a file.

Try to run with sqoop instead of sqoop2, the same command should work most likely.

**UPDATE** after yours:

After checking the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.5-cdh5.4.4/org/apache/sqoop/manager/OracleManager.java#759) at the exception, pretty much one thing can be null at that point, the connection object, which means the getConnection() call earlier in this method got a null as a result, which by further checking the code could not happen, that means, an SQLException was thrown while trying to make the connection, and it stays hidden because of the NPE in the catch.

Check your DB logs, connection string and such... Especially because you are using -P option, and still got the warning about it in the output.

Comment: It gives an other error that you have already updated in the question, which as well makes my answer a little silly. :)

Comment: You can even try the same connection string, user name, and password with the java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection.

Comment: I was using the password. sorry for confusion. Not sure where you want me to put this: java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection

Comment: sqlplus is not installed in this server. sqlplus
-bash: sqlplus: command not found

Comment: Also I am not using SID anywhere. It is same as my database name.

Comment: java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection is a method used as well in the code, I meant you can try to write a java code and test if you can connect with it or if the sample code says any more useful info, as well as you can check the db logs if it says what is the issue with the connection.